# How can I implement such a schedule?

Tags: highcharts

I am developing a graph in javascript and I need a similar graph
Specifically, I'm interested in the moment on the right where one graph transitions to the other transparent[image]

Comment: This is a simplified example of a column chart you can base on: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zjk1ocb7/ (Official demo: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic) In this example, columns are fading after hover, is it your looking for or can you clarify when column should be transparent?

Comment: I want to pass two kinds of data to display non-transparent and transparent bars
Or one type, but that columns (transparent and non-transparent) are always displayed

Comment: You can achieve such an example by disabling `grouping` for series and setting `pointPadding` and `pointPlacement`.  Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/y5j7vLud/ . Let me know if that was what you were looking for

Comment: For certain circumstances, I use this method jsfiddle.net/r1d6tozq/29 How can I center the columns between the ticks as in the screenshot above?

Comment: Set your xAxis as a `category` type and add `tickWidth` Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3anj1749/

Comment: Your solution works fine, but not for my example with period year https://jsfiddle.net/cw4tsfpv/42/

Comment: Yes, If you define x values with such a density of data, the above method will not work as you expect. I passed the answer In the thread you have created: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73815625/how-can-i-plot-the-x-axis-on-a-highchart-like-this