# How can I plot the x-axis on a highchart like this?

Tags: highcharts

I'm building a chart using the highcharts javascript library
I'm expecting to get a chart like [image: this]
And here's what I already have.   [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/cw4tsfpv/71/)

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You define x values on a categorized axis and because of the default `pointPlacement`, your chart is distorted. You can change `pointRange`, but in that case, I would recommend removing axis type (the linear will be by default) and set `series.pointPlacement` to `between`

```
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      pointPlacement: "between"
    }
  },
```

The label's position can be set by `xAxis.labels.x` option.

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/a4qs7dp9/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointRange
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointPlacement
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.x